# How can I find what optic is in an interface for a Juniper MX-series router?

Tags: juniper, optics

As the title states, how can I see what optic I have installed in an interface for an MX router?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to be looking under the [`show chassis hardware`](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos12.1/topics/reference/command-summary/show-chassis-hardware.html) stanza.  That gives you all the inner-workings of the devices plugged into the chassis, including VC members.

On an MX platform, this is along the lines of what you'd expect:

```
user@host> show chassis hardware
Hardware inventory:
Item             Version  Part number  Serial number     Description
Chassis                                E1372             MX10-T
Midplane         REV 01   711-038211   YF5285            MX10-T
PEM 0            Rev 04   740-028288   VB01678           AC Power Entry Module
Routing Engine            BUILTIN      BUILTIN           Routing Engine
TFEB 0                    BUILTIN      BUILTIN           Forwarding Engine Processor
  QXM 0          REV 05   711-028408   ZA9053            MPC QXM
FPC 0                     BUILTIN      BUILTIN           MPC BUILTIN
  MIC 0                   BUILTIN      BUILTIN           4x 10GE XFP
    PIC 0                 BUILTIN      BUILTIN           4x 10GE XFP
FPC 1                     BUILTIN      BUILTIN           MPC BUILTIN
  MIC 0          REV 24   750-028392   YX9436            3D 20x 1GE(LAN) SFP
    PIC 0                 BUILTIN      BUILTIN           10x 1GE(LAN) SFP
      Xcvr 0     REV 01   740-031851   AM1107SUFQW       SFP-SX
    PIC 1                 BUILTIN      BUILTIN           10x 1GE(LAN) SFP
Fan Tray                                                 Fan Tray
```

*<sup>Sample information derived from [Juniper TechLibrary](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos12.1/topics/reference/command-summary/show-chassis-hardware.html#jd0e1039)</sup>*

Or perhaps you don't buy *everything* from Juniper and/or you live in a multi vendor environment (like me).  Your system will look eerily similar to this:

```
FPC 0            REV 20   750-045402   LX0XXXXXXXXX      EX4550-32F
  CPU                     BUILTIN      BUILTIN           FPC CPU
  PIC 0                   BUILTIN      BUILTIN           32x 1G/10G SFP/SFP+
    Xcvr 0       REV 01   740-021309   ARS0HB7           SFP+-10G-LR
    Xcvr 1       REV 01   740-021309   ARS0HB2           SFP+-10G-LR
    Xcvr 12      c        NON-JNPR     FNS0838H4CB       SFP-LX10
    Xcvr 13               NON-JNPR     FNS0838H4AJ       SFP-LX10
    Xcvr 14      M        NON-JNPR     FNS0835T08U       SFP-LX10
    Xcvr 15               NON-JNPR     FNS0838H4B0       SFP-LX10
    Xcvr 16      U        NON-JNPR     FNS0835T0C2       SFP-LX10
```

Although this is on an EX4550, the transceivers marked `NON-JNPR` would show up the same on an MX platform.  It's not a malfunction, the system just doesn't recognize the device signatures.  If you want additional information on them, such as the vendor, fiber wavelength, or fiber type, use the [`show chassis pic fpc-slot <FPC> pic-slot <PIC>`](http://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos13.3/topics/reference/command-summary/show-chassis-pic.html).

```
rj@MHN00525CN01> show chassis pic fpc-slot 0 pic-slot 0
FPC slot 0, PIC slot 0 information:
  Type                             32x 1G/10G SFP/SFP+ Builtin
  State                            Online
  Uptime                         56 days, 6 hours, 5 minutes, 6 seconds

PIC port information:
                         Fiber                    Xcvr vendor       Wave-    Xcvr
  Port Cable type        type  Xcvr vendor        part number       length   Firmware
  0    10GBASE LR        SM    FINISAR CORP.      FTLX1471D3BCL-J1  1310 nm  0.0
  1    10GBASE LR        SM    FINISAR CORP.      FTLX1471D3BCL-J1  1310 nm  0.0
  12   GIGE 1000LX10     SM    CISCO-FINISAR      FTRJ-1319-7D-CSC  1310 nm  0.0
  13   GIGE 1000LX10     SM    CISCO-FINISAR      FTRJ-1319-7D-CSC  1310 nm  0.0
  14   GIGE 1000LX10     SM    CISCO-FINISAR      FTRJ-1319-7D-CSC  1310 nm  0.0
  15   GIGE 1000LX10     SM    CISCO-FINISAR      FTRJ-1319-7D-CSC  1310 nm  0.0
  16   GIGE 1000LX10     SM    CISCO-FINISAR      FTRJ-1319-7D-CSC  1310 nm  0.0
```

Most of the time, though, `show chassis hardware` will be more than sufficient.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the output of

```
show chassis hardware
```

and

```
show chassis pic fpc-slot <X> pic-slot <Y>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
show chassis pic fpc-slot 1 pic-slot 0
```

Answer (score 0):

In general:

`show chassis hardware`

In particular, if you don't get enough information there you can try:

`show chassis fpc pic-status`

`show chassis pic pic-slot PIC_ID fpc-slot FPC_ID` (substitute with the proper IDs of course)

Answer (score -1):

I found this which helps me when using the show chassis command:

[image]

Comment: Although this is a nice diagram, it doesn't seem to answer the question. The OP is asking to discover which type of optics are actually installed , not what the port numbers are.